# AttributeError: 'GMM' object has no attribute 'covariances_' || AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GaussianMixture'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a snippet of code to fit the guassian model for my data. I have imported mixture from sklearn. However even I use mixture.GaussianMixture I get an error:AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GaussianMixture' and if I use the other way, it gives an error: AttributeError: 'GMM' object has no attribute 'covariances_'. I even tried importing covariance but doean't seem to work. Could anyone please let me know how to fix this error.

```
from sklearn import mixture   

# Fit a Gaussian mixture with EM using five components
gmm = mixture.GaussianMixture(n_components=5, covariance_type='full').fit(X) 
gmm = GMM(n_components=3, covariance_type='full')
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the new versions from 0.18 onwards, GMM has been deprecated and GaussianMixture is used in place of that as can be seen in the [documentation here.](http://scikit-learn.org/0.18/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GMM.html#sklearn.mixture.GMM)

Now for your first error, it seems that you have an older version of scikit-learn which dont have the GaussianMixture class yet. And for your second error, older GMM did not have the attribute `covariances_`. Use `covars_` attribute instead. See the older [documentation here](http://scikit-learn.org/0.17/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GMM.html#sklearn.mixture.GMM):-

> covars_ : array
>
> ```
> Covariance parameters for each mixture component. 
> The shape depends on covariance_type:
> ```

Then it wont throw any error.

Update the scikit-learn to the newest version to use the `covariances_` attribute in the GaussianMixture class.

Comment: Updating the version of scikit learn to 0.18 worked :) Thanks